# How do I convert SQL data from one view to this other view in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have table with data like this

```
id group order value
-------------------------
1  1     1     23
2  1     2     34
3  2     1     234
4  2     2     77
5  2     3     102
```

I want to insert into table so I have one row per group, with the value showing a string of comma-separated values orders based on the order.

```
id group value
----------------
1  1     23,34
2  2     234,77,102
```

How do I do this? I'm using Postgres 9.3

Comment: I think you'll want to self join the table on `group` and use `CONCAT`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Postgres supports `string_agg()`:

```
select row_number() over () as id, "group", string_agg(value, ',' order by "order")
from t
group by "group";
```

Comment: Thanks nearly have it with  'select string_agg(value::text, ',') from t group by group;' but when I add in the order by "order" I get syntax error

Comment: Must have had a typo in there, now working, thankyou !

Comment: I have another condition, sometimes the value column can have a null. If a group has any rows with a NULL for value then I dont want a row for that group, how would I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

I would look at PostgreSQL's [string_agg](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-aggregate.html) aggregate function.